# not authorized bing search api

Tags: java, azure

the following code :

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
try{
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(x);
request.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic:accound id");
ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
String responseBody = client.execute(request, responseHandler);
System.out.println(responseBody);
}
```

where x = ="https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/SearchWeb/vl/Web?Query=%27query%20";

gives following error :
org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: The authorization type you provided is not supported.  Only Basic and OAuth are supported
what could be solution fo it?

Answer (score 1):

The authorization header needs to be Base64 encoded; username is left empty, password is account id.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!changing the code by adding byte[] accountKeyBytes = Base64.encodeBase64((x + ":" + x).getBytes());//x is key;request.setHeader("Authorization","Basic : " + x);//leaving authorization blank giving bad request and like this same error as not authorized.

Comment: You're appending the key twice currently. Try: ``Base64.encodeBase64(":" + key)``

Answer (score 0):

the code should be something like

---

```
String accountKey = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
byte[] accountKeyBytes = Base64.encodeBase64((accountKey + ":" + accountKey).getBytes());      String accountKeyEnc = new String(accountKeyBytes);
request.setHeader("Authorization",
                "Basic" + " "+accountKeyEnc);
```